# Left Join and SUM on two tables, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains information about an item, and another table that references the owner of that item, like so:

```
baseItem
--------
itemID   |  1   |   2   |  3  |  4  |
itemSize |  5   |   1   |  5  |  3  |
itemCost | 100  |  50   |  1  |  99 |

itemOwner
--------
ownerID  |  1  |  1  |  3
itemID   |  1  |  4  |  2
```

What I'm after are the SUMS of itemSize and itemCOST based on the owner. I've looked around but none of the answers I've seen make sense? Here's the best I could come up with, which clearly isn't working:

```
SUM itemCost FROM baseItem.itemCost LEFT JOIN itemID ON itemOwner.itemid = baseItem.itemid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ownerId, sum(itemCost) as OwnerCost,  sum(itemSize) as OwnerSize
FROM itemOwner
LEFT JOIN baseItem
  ON itemOwner.itemid = baseItem.itemid
GROUP BY ownerId
```

A `SELECT` statement lists which fields you want to read from the table; in this case you want two values: the `id` of the owner, and the sum of the values of the items they own. However, since you're using `sum` (an aggregate function), you must `GROUP` your elements over some parameter. In this case, you want to group them by `ownerId`.

A `FROM` clause references a table; you can start with either `baseItem` or `itemOwner`, it makes no difference in this case. You can think of `LEFT JOIN` as a cartesian product that creates a new table, which contains every element from the cartesian product of both, filtered by the `ON` clause. However will always have all the items in the left table which is `itemOwner` and when there are no matching rows in the baseItem all the fields will be `NULL`. The SUM function will act as if those are 0s and should return you a 0 sum for non matching rows in the `baseItem` table.

Comment: I haven't try it but it looks like you need to GROUP BY ownerId to make it works

Comment: Indeed, that's what happens when I write quickly :P

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but this doesn't appear to be working...  should I be fetching this as an array or an object?

Comment: Also, here's the code I'm using:
`SELECT ownerID WHERE ownerID='$ownervariable',` `sum(baseItem.itemCost)`
`FROM baseItem ON itemOwner.itemid = baseItem.itemid`
`GROUP BY ownerID`

Comment: If your question is about PHP, please tag it as such. It should make no difference whether it's an array or an object. The syntax is `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE`, not `SELECT field WHERE, field FROM`.

Comment: In this case, you don't even want a `GROUP BY`, you want the sum of the costs for a particular owner, so... `SELECT sum(itemCost) FROM itemOwner JOIN baseItem ON itemOwner.itemid = baseItem.itemid WHERE ownerId = '$ownervariable'`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not working because it is invalid SQL statement. Try following code

```
SELECT SUM(baseItem.itemCost) FROM baseItem 
   LEFT JOIN itemOwner ON itemOwner.itemId = baseItem.itemId
```